# Use mathematical logic to write the next sentence : For all positive x between 0 and 1, x squared is smaller than x

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am trying to write the sentence

Like this : ∀x((x<1)∧(x>0))→∀x((x^2)<x)

Is there any error here, or is it a suitable solution to the question ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I would omit the second $\forall x$

Comment: But apart from that , the expression is valid.

Comment: Remove the second $\forall x$. That is a mistake because these $x$'s are in fact the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the second $\forall x$.  $x$ has the same value throughout the statement.  Some demand there be a set of parentheses around the whole scope of a quantifier.  If you do, you should have a set around the whole implication.

Comment: It seems to me that some changes also need to be made in the parenthesizing, in order to make sure the opening quantifier extends over the entire implication. (As currently written, the statement says that one for-all statement implies a second for-all statement. At least that's how I parse the placement of parentheses in a "$\forall x(P(x))$" formula.)

Comment: @BarryCipra:  I misread it.  I thought there were enclosing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone, the statement is false, informative comments and answers 
As I understand this is the right way you do it :
∀x(((x<1)∧(x>0))→((x^2)<x))